# AspCore - tsconfig not respected

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, typescript2.0

I created a new asp core project . I want to use in it typescript 2.0 and angular 2.

I installed typescript globaly and have it in the packages

The Project can be compiled using gulp and I see a valid javascript file as a result

But in the IDE of VisualStudio I get errors indicating that the tsconfig is not loaded. Nevertheless i see in the virtual typescript project the tsconfig so I asume it has been loaded.

Also I can see that the dependencies have a warning signal, but all pacakges were installed. and there are no important errors when i run reinstall

[image]

My Projectstructure looks like this

[image]

my tsconfig has this content

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/app"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "files": [
    "../typings/main.d.ts",
      "./*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you install the TypeScript 2.0 VIsual Studio tools?

Comment: yes. it came out that it worked after removing the files section from the tsconfig I took it as it was part of a example of asp core and typescript. Also the tutorial I used was outdated and there were some references bugs. so i remvoed all installed typings and modules and reinstalled with the config from the so called angular quicktstart tutorial and it worked